# Is it possible to get the non-borrowed type from Self?

Tags: rust, operator-overloading

I am creating a `Vector2` type in Rust using the newtype pattern over an array:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Vector2([f64; 2]);
```

I have implemented the add operator on `&Vector2`, but I would like to know if I can specify the output type from `Self`. That is, I have `Self` which is a `&Vector2` and I want to know whether I can "dereference" `Self` to get the type `Vector2`.

I have the following code, which works, but I would like to know if I can replace the line `type Output = Vector2;` with something like `type Output = *Self;`

```rust
impl std::ops::Add for &Vector2 {
    type Output = Vector2;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Vector2 {
        Vector2 {
            0: [self.0[0] + other.0[0], self.0[1] + other.0[1]]
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution to this problem as pointed out by @rodrigo and @Frxstrem in the comments to the other answer is to use `<Self as Deref>::Target`. This works for types implementing the Deref trait.

```rust
impl std::ops::Add for &Vector2 {
    type Output = <Self as Deref>::Target;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `*Self` as is, but you can get what you want with an auxiliary trait and a blanket implementation:

```
trait Pointer {
    type Pointed;
}
impl<T> Pointer for &T {
    type Pointed = T;
}
```

Now you can write your code as:

```
impl std::ops::Add for &Vector2 {
    type Output = <Self as Pointer>::Pointed;
    //...
}
```

Naturally, you will want to add also impls for `&mut T`, `*const T` and `*mut T`.

I guess that there should be a crate that does exactly this, but I didn't found it. When I needed it I just wrote it verbatim.

Comment: Personally I'd probably just use the built-in [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait (and the associated `Deref::Target` type) for this, as that seems to represent the concept of a "pointer" pretty well. It is also what is used for example in the [`Pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html) type to represent a generic pointer type.

Comment: @Frxstrem Using `<Self as Deref>::Target` is the correct answer here – would you like to add this as a separate answer?

Comment: @Frxstrem: Of course you are right! I had to write this once for raw pointers, that don't implement `Deref`, and just copied&pasted my solution here. Feel free to add another, better answer (or edit mine, if you wish).

Comment: `<Self as Deref>::Target` does indeed work! @rodrigo I would add this as a second answer, which I will then accept, since the other solution may still be useful in other use cases.